# Is it annoying that I don't answer questions and just ask?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

Hi I'm pretty new with math.se, well I think I am, I have been getting a lot of great answers from a lot of smart and reliable people. However, I am starting to feel kinda bad because I never answer questions. It just seems like whenever there's a question that I can answer, it's already answered. Is it (for lack of a better word) "annoying" that I dont answer questions and just ask?

Comment: Yes, this is kind of meta, but it's a good reminder to beginners about the aims of this wonderful site.  I think his question does a service.

Comment: Maybe change the title to reflect the question, and delete the improper integral?

Comment: Edited in accord with comments.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In a word, the answer is 'no.' As long as you are asking thoughtful questions that are coming from a real desire to learn (and have not already been asked), you will find that people are pleased to answer. Remember that the questions that you ask, and their answers, stick around for years to come and will benefit others on down the line.

Comment: Well said, treble.  I agree with your comments 100%.

Comment: @treble Great, thanks for the answer I feel better now.

Comment: @Kyle: To add just a little to what treble said, with which I agree completely: some of us are here because we like answering questions. Good questions are our gain as much as good answers are yours.

Comment: +1. But sometimes we receive bad comments based on our low acceptance. I asked some hard questions and they took me some days to understand and accept them. But I agree that the questions move the world.

Comment: @treble The questions will benefit others down the line, as long as the answers are accurate.

Answer (score 26):

Kyle, use this forum to learn.  As you gain expertise, you will be able to answer questions too.  Good questions are the grist that makes this forum go.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to do so

Comment: @Kyle this is the way to think about it. When I first registered for Stack Overflow about two years ago, I had never programmed anything beyond simple "hello world" style programs. But people patiently answered my beginner questions, and I learned from their answers, and now I'm one of the top-rated users in some tags. Keep at it!

Comment: MSE seems much more forgiving than [freemathhelp.com](http://www.freemathhelp.com/forum/)

Answer (score 8):

If nobody asked, not much would happen. I might suggest that you do read all the answers and upvote the ones that are useful. And, quite important, do accept an answer. Of course, if you feel uncertain or that your question has not been resolved, then ask further.